Grub Menu not showing after clean installation of Windows 11
So , I dual boot my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11. Today I made a clean installation of Windows 11 , due to some issues. Before that whenever I turn on my pc, it shows the Grub Menu, where I can select the os to boot into. But after the clean installation, the pc directly boots into Windows 11, not showing the grub Menu. I restarted the windows 11 using Shift+Restart to enter the Windows Recovery Mode, from where I booted into the Linux partition. How to enable the grub menu like before?

Does this answer your question? How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)

If UEFI installs, can you boot Ubuntu from UEFI one time boot menu? Is UEFI Secure boot now on, and Ubuntu installed with it off?  And then if Ubuntu boots, go into UEFI settings (not UEFI menu) and change boot order? Note that Windows updates may turn fast startup back on or new Windows may have bitlocker on, which may prevent grub os-prober from adding Windows to grub menu. You can always boot from UEFI one time boot menu or turn off Windows fast startup & bitlocker.

Does this answer your question? Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot

I figured another simple way out of this, as the Grub Menu appears when I manually boot into Ubuntu, so I changed the Ubuntu to 1st in Boot Order, thus showing the grub menu and Windows to 2nd

A clean Windows setup will hijack the boot partition created by grub. You'll either have to chroot with a live USB stick and reinstall grub, or you'll need to do a full install (overwriting the existing Linux partition).

I figured another simple way out of this, as the Grub Menu appears when I manually boot into Ubuntu, so I changed the Ubuntu to 1st in Boot Order, thus showing the grub menu..

Very cool, thanks for sharing - I didn't know that this works with UEFI
